# Routing problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, config, app-startup

I previously had the routes on my MVC4 applications configured using the RouteConfig.cs file found in app start with the following default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Having branched my application to allow for Forms authentication having been initially developed using ADFS authentication I needed to change the default URL of the site to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is working in so much that it is taking the user to the Account/Login page initially but where previously the user could type /Admin to get to the Admin/Index page these are no longer applied. How can I reestablish the Index page as the default for the controller while keeping the Account/Login as the primary page

Comment: You could redirect the user to the account/login page from home/index if the user hasn't signed in.

Answer (score 0):

You may define a more specific route for the Admin part **before** your generic route for Login :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "admin/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```